# Minimum y-value for $ y=x^x $

Tags: calculus

I’m  trying to find the minimum y-value for $ y=x^x ,x>0 $, I assumed y would approach 0 as x approached 0, but after plotting the graph, It seems the minimum y-value is when x is around 0.25~0.5, but I cannot make any further progress.

Comment: let $y'(x)=0$, try to solve x.

Answer (score 5):

Take the logarithm and use implicit differentiation.

$$\ln y = x \ln x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln y = (\frac{d}{dx} x) \ln x + x(\frac{d}{dx} \ln x)$$
$$\frac{1}{y} y' = \ln(x) + 1$$
$$y' = y(\ln(x) + 1)$$
$$y' = x^x(\ln(x) + 1)$$

Setting $y' = 0$, we get either $x^x = 0$ or $\ln(x) + 1 = 0$.  The former is impossible, so we must have

$$\ln(x) + 1 = 0$$
$$\ln(x) = -1$$
$$x = e^{-1} = \frac{1}{e} \approx 0.367879$$

The corresponding $y$ value is $\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{e}} = e^{-1/e} \approx 0.692201$.